# how to create criteria with join in yii

Tags: yii

I have to tables, one is `profile` and the other is `rating`. 
`rating` has a field `profileid` which is primary key to `profile.id` and a field with rating values. Now I want to find the field with highest rating and display the corresponding profile. Since I'm new to YII framework I'm having troubles with it. Please help me getting out of it. What I'm doing is described below.

```
$topRage=new CDbCriteria();
$topRage->select="*";
$topRage->alias="t1";
$topRage->order="rateing DESC";
$topRage->join="JOIN `ratings` ON `profile`.`id` = `t1`.`profileId`";
$topRage->limit="1";
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#alias-detail

Comment: what is the trouble? your code is good, where exactly do you want help?

Comment: @bool.dev its not working i want to get the profile with highest rating and its rating too both are in different tables ratings and profile

Comment: @bool.dev i dont know its showing error   throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: {error}',

Comment: ok..it must be showing the sql statement that is being executed, can you paste that part of the error?

Comment: @bool.dev $message .= '. The SQL statement executed was: '.$this->getText().$par;

Comment: @bool.dev 'Ratings' => Ratings::model()->findAll($topRage), this is how i rendering it

Comment: show how you are using that findAll, because obviously the statement is not sql. There could be some error in how you are calling findAll

Comment: error occurs when i use join statement else working fine

Comment: @bool.dev can u send me any example using join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
join='JOIN profile ON profile.id = t1.profileId';
```

If you are doing this: `Ratings::model()->findAll($topRage)` , then ratings table is already being queried, so you need to join with profile table.

**Edit:**

for echo you'll need to do this:

```
$echo "Rating id: ".$rating->id."|&nbspProfile Id: ".$rating->profile->id."|&nbspProfile Name: ".$rating->profile->name."|&nbspRating: ".$rating->ratingvalue;
```

Don't forget to pass `$rating` from the controller though.

You could also use `find($topRage)` instead of the `findAll($topRage)` and remove the `limit`, but that 's just another way of doing the same thing.

Comment: its working so now how i will now echo  the content of profile table

Comment: @Bipin i have edited my answer, with echo statements, check it out

Answer (score 1):

just query without join .

```
$topRage=new CDbCriteria();
$topRage->select="*";
$topRage->alias="t1";
$topRage->order="rateing DESC";
$topRage->limit="1";

$rating=Ratings::model()->findAll($topRage);
$profile=Profile::model()->findByPk($rating->profileId);
```